# Am I missing a check for the actions in the given state?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

The problem:
Three traditional, but jealous, couples need to cross a river. Each couple consists of a husband and a wife. They find a small boat that can contain no more than two persons. Find the simplest schedule of crossings that will permit all six people to cross the river so that none of the women shall be left in company with any of the men, unless her husband is present. It is assumed that all passengers on the boat onboard before the next trip and at least one person has to be in the boat for each crossing.

Had to edit out code, was requested by professor.

I've been working on this problem for 6 hours and I am stumped. My professor is busy and cannot help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I toke a careful look on your code. It is indeed a very interesting problem and quite complex. After some while I realized that what maybe causing your problem is that your are checking the conditions before the crossing is made and not afterwords. A saw the template you provided and I guess we can try to stick with to logic proposed by 1- make the action method return all possible crosses (without checking the states yet) 2- given each action, get the corresponding new state and check if that state is valid. 3- make the value() method to check if we are making progress on the optimization.

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self, initial_state, goal):
        self.goal = goal
        self.record = [[0, initial_state, "LEFT", []]]
            # list of results [score][state][boat_side][listActions]

    def actions(self, state, boat_side):
        side = 0 if boat_side == 'LEFT' else 1
        boat_dir = 'RIGHT' if boat_side == 'LEFT' else 'LEFT'

        group = [i for i, v in enumerate(state) if v == side]
        onboard_2 = [[boat_dir, a, b] for a in group for b in group if 
            a < b and (     # not the same person and unique group 
            (a%2==0 and b - a == 1) or (        # wife and husband
            a%2==0 and b%2==0) or (             # two wife's
            a%2==1 and b%2==1)                  # two husbands
        )]
        onboard_1 = [[boat_dir, a] for a in group]
        return onboard_1 + onboard_2

    def result(self, state, action):
        new_boat_side = action[0]
        new_state = []
        for i, v in enumerate(state):
            if i in action[1:]:
                new_state.append(1 if v == 0 else 0)
            else:
                new_state.append(v)

        # check if invalid
        for p, side, in enumerate(new_state):
            if p%2 == 0: # is woman
                if side != new_state[p+1]: # not with husband
                    if any(men == side for men in new_state[1::2]):
                        new_state = False
                        break

        return new_state, new_boat_side

    def goal_test(self, state):
        return state == self.goal

    def value(self, state):
        # how many people already crossed
        return state.count(1)


# optimization process
initial_state = [0]*6
goal = [1]*6
task = Problem(initial_state, goal)

while True:
    batch_result = []
    for score, state, side, l_a in task.record:
        possible_actions = task.actions(state, side)
        for a in possible_actions:
            new_state, new_boat_side = task.result(state, a)
            if new_state: # is a valid state
                batch_result.append([
                    task.value(new_state),
                    new_state,
                    new_boat_side,
                    l_a + a,
                ])

    batch_result.sort(key= lambda x: x[0], reverse= True)
        # sort the results with the most people crossed
    task.record = batch_result[:5]
        # I am only sticking with the best 5 results but
        #   any number should be fine on this problem
    if task.goal_test(task.record[0][1]):
        break

#   for i in task.record[:5]: # uncomment these lines to see full progress
#       print(i)
#   x = input() # press any key to continue

print(task.record[0][3])
```

I hope it helped, please fill free to say if anything is still not so clear.

Comment: Wow! I wasn't expecting anyone to answer this question. I was starting to think the same, I am checking the state before the crossing is made, which might cause some issues. I tinkered with it for a bit, but the deadline ran out so I just submitted what I had.

You went above and beyond, I am seriously so thankful. I've accepted your answer, I really appreciate your time.

Comment: Just curious, do you know where I screwed up in my code? I know my code is poor compared to yours, but I'd love to know where I screwed up, as I was trying to test for the same things haha. I've already marked your answer as the accepted one, so you don't have to respond, but I'd love to know where I screwed up. Again, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Jamie, thanks for the king response. The first thing I did was try to make your code run, so I tried your idea to make the action(state) method only return crossings that would lead to valid states. The problem is that you have to check for 1- the cross is valid (ok in your code); 2- the state after the cross is made is valid (missing on your code). So when I started making all the possible checks that a crossing would lead to a valid state I realized it was better to make a valid state overall check.

Comment: from the first state your action() method returns "[('RIGHT', 0), ('RIGHT', 1), ('RIGHT', 2), ('RIGHT', 3), ('RIGHT', 4), ('RIGHT', 5), ('RIGHT', 0, 1), ('RIGHT', 0, 2), ('RIGHT', 0, 3), ('RIGHT', 0, 4), ('RIGHT', 0, 5), ('RIGHT', 1, 0), ('RIGHT', 1, 2), ('RIGHT', 1, 3), ('RIGHT', 1, 4), [...to long] ('RIGHT', 3, 5), ('RIGHT', 4, 0), ('RIGHT', 4, 1), ('RIGHT', 4, 2), ('RIGHT', 4, 3), ('RIGHT', 4, 5), ('RIGHT', 5, 0), ('RIGHT', 5, 1), ('RIGHT', 5, 2), ('RIGHT', 5, 3), ('RIGHT', 5, 4)]" so your valid_state() isnt working as supposed because its not checking the afterwards state

Comment: if you see your valid_state and my 'check if invalid' they are almost the same, the difference is where they are placed on the code. In order to make your code work you have to make a overall valid state check in your result function and discard the invalid states on your optimization process.

Comment: I see now! I'll try to implement it and report back, thank you again, you're the best.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222824/discussion-between-jamie-smith-and-tatarana).